# Sort a Arraylist Object

Tags: java, android, sorting, arraylist

I have Arraylist

```
Arraylist<Class> arraylist = new Arraylist<>();
```

Class Contains Different Elements like name,age,roll no.

i Want to sort this arraylist and Using

```
Collections.sort(arraylist);
```

and getting an error how can i sort this arraylist with roll no. in android studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use lambda functions (Java 8) which does not require you to implement Comparable class and does the job right.

General syntax:

```
Collections.sort(students, (s1, s2) ->
        s1.getName().compareTo(s2.getName())); // for String values


Collections.sort(students, (s1, s2) ->
        Integer.compare(s1.getRollNumber(), s2.getRollNumber())); // for Integral values
```

ArrayList would be:

```
List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();
```

This is for the class

```
class Student{
    String name;
    int rollNumber;

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }

    public int getRollNumber(){
        return rollNumber;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a `Comparator<Class>` to compare elements during sort operation. One example could be:

```
class ClassComparator implements Comparator<Class> {

    @Override
    public int compare(Class c1, Class c2) {
        // write comparison logic here like below , it's just a sample
        return c1.name.compareTo(c2.name);
    }
}
```

Then use the Comparator as

```
Collections.sort(arraylist, new ClassComparator());
```

An alternative way to do the same thing is to implement `Comparable` interface in `Class` class:

```
class Class implements Comparable<Class> {

    public String name;

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Class o) {
        return name.compareTo(o.name);
    }
}
```

Then call:

```
Collections.sort(arraylist);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your class for e.g. should be sortable before you sort it. It's essential for the Collections.sort() to know on what criteria should it sort the list. Unless you want to explicitly implement Comparable or create a Compratator (the old way pre java 8) you can do the following

```
class Student {
    private int rollNumber;
    private String name;

    public int getRollNumber() {
        return rollNumber;
    }

    public void setRollNumber(int rollNumber) {
        this.rollNumber = rollNumber;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Then you can sort the list as :

```
Collections.sort(list, Comparator.comparingInt(Student::getRollNumber));
```